# Unity cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "bool"

Tags: c#, ios

So, I am trying to create a quiz, probably the hardest way possible knowing me, and this error keeps popping up (title of thread). This is the code, anyone know whats wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class score : MonoBehaviour {

public string final_score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (final_score = ("10"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Result1");
    }

    if (final_score = ("20"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Result2");
    }

    if (final_score = ("30"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Result3");
    }

    if (final_score = ("40"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Result4");
    }

    if (final_score = ("50"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Result5");
    }

    if (final_score = ("60"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Result6");
    }

  }

}
```

That's my main problem, but if at all possible, anyone know a good tutorial for a quiz app in unity? I am using the basic stuff to create it now, but I feel like there is a way easier way to do it and I don't know what that is. I found some tutorials, but none are what I need. My quiz has 8 questions, each with 4 answers. I need each answer to add up to determine a final result, which there are 6 of. I am using a scene for each question/result, should I change that? But if I did that how would I get the questions/answers to spawn in correctly? My main problem with the entire quiz is the results. How do I get the questions to add up through the different scenes to determine a result? Thanks! This project is on a schedule and needs to be done tomorrow, so fast results would be great! Please make sure the fixes/tutorials work on iOS and other mobile devices.

Comment: use '==' instead of '=' in the if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your comparison operator being wrong , score seems like it should be an integer.

You can also avoid the if statement, by using a dictionary , or a similar data structure.

```
Dictionary<int, string> quiz =
        new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 10, "Result1" },
    { 20, "Result2" },
    { 30, "Result3" },
    { 40, "Result4" },
    { 50, "Result5" },
    { 60, "Result6" }
};

void Update (int score) {
    Application.LoadLevel(quiz[score]);
}
```

Comment: @NuckG you need to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` of course, as for your second question it is not clear at all, maybe you can edit your post, and ask 1 not many ones

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will be making another question for that explaining it a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

[`=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is assignment operator, you need to use [`==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) which is equality operator.

Your

```
final_score = ("10")
```

line and other lines are executed as

- assign `"10"` to your `final_score` variable
- return this string object.

Since if statement expect [boolean expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression), and there is no implicit conversation between `string` and `bool` types, you get this error.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I forgot about that part. Still looking for an answer to the second question though!

Answer (score 2):

update you code `=` to `==` like this way because `=` operator is assignment.

```
void Update () {

if (final_score == ("10"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Result1");
}

if (final_score == ("20"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Result2");
}

if (final_score == ("30"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Result3");
}

if (final_score == ("40"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Result4");
}

if (final_score ==("50"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Result5");
}

if (final_score == ("60"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Result6");
}

  }
```